# Detectron2 pre-trained model using layoutparser in Docker container Error: Checkpoint Not Found

Tags: python, machine-learning, ocr, detectron, layout-parser

following is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.9
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update
pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install layoutparser 

RUN pip install "layoutparser[ocr]" 

RUN pip install pytesseract 

RUN pip install pdf2image 

RUN pip install torch 

RUN pip install torchvision

RUN apt-get install -y poppler-utils  #(pdf-image) 

RUN apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr 

RUN apt-get install git #(to install detectron2) 

RUN pip install "git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git"  #(detectron2 model) 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y #(required to run packages)

workdir /home/jovyan/work/layout_parser

volume ["/home/jovyan/work/layout_parser"]

CMD ["python", "test_code.py"]
```

python code test_code.py:

```
import pdf2image
import layoutparser as lp
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


pdf_file= r"/home/jovyan/work/layout_parser/test_pdf.pdf"
image = np.asarray(pdf2image.convert_from_path(pdf_file)[0])

model = lp.Detectron2LayoutModel('lp://PubLayNet/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/config')
```

I received the following error:
[image]

I have tried the following to resolve the issue without any success:

- variations of torch and torchvision versions used
- python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 base used
- variations of pre-built model's config_path used
- Manually downloaded model as present in the config file ->  [layout_parser_modelzoo](https://layout-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/modelzoo.html)
- tried manually downloaded model in extension pth and pkl. Received the following error:
  [image]

How could I use the pre-trained models?

Comment: Was facing the same issue.
This helped me fix:
https://github.com/Layout-Parser/layout-parser/issues/15#:~:text=Aug%204%2C%202022-,One%20workaround%20I%20found%20is%2C%20to%20change%20the%20WEIGHTS%20path%20inside%20the%20config.yaml%20file.,-If%20the%20path

Answer (score 0):

I got it to run with the following steps:

1. download the correct yaml file from here: https://github.com/Layout-Parser/layout-parser/blob/main/src/layoutparser/models/detectron2/catalog.py (from CONFIG_CATALOG, starting at line 45) and place it in your directory
2. load detectron model like this:

`cv_model = lp.Detectron2LayoutModel( config_path ='config.yml', # In model catalog label_map   ={0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 3:"Table", 4:"Figure"}, # In model`label_map `extra_config=["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST", 0.8] # Optional )`
where the label map has to correspond to the config file with the same name

3. In the config file the model checkpoints are written like:   `WEIGHTS: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9fc9tahfzyl6df/model_final.pth?dl=1` weights will be loaded from there when running the script